# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] during writing numbers to file on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, file, save

I have wierd problem with saving to file. On Linux this code works like charm, but on Windows I got `FileNotFoundError`... and couple weeks ago everything worked like it should be... Any solutions?

Here is my code:

```
def save_nums_to_file(self):
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    final_directory_results, final_directory_data_numbers = os.path.join(current_directory, r'Data Results'), os.path.join(current_directory, r'Data Numbers')
    if not os.path.exists(final_directory_results) or os.path.exists(final_directory_data_numbers):
        os.makedirs(final_directory_results, exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs(final_directory_data_numbers, exist_ok=True)

    with open('Data Numbers/'+ str(len(self.tab_generated)) + '_numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in self.tab_generated:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Error:

```
File "C:/Users/pzdebski/Documents/Gotowa Apka/MainFile.py", line 922, in <module> gd.save_nums_to_file() File "C:/Users/pzdebski/Documents/Gotowa Apka/MainFile.py", line 93, in save_nums_to_file os.makedirs(final_directory_results, exist_ok=True) File "C:\Users\pzdebski\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs mkdir(name, mode) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku: 'C:\\Users\\pzdebski\\Documents\\Gotowa Apka\\Data Results'
```

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: `if not os.path.exists(final_directory_results) or os.path.exists(....)`. You forgot `not` after `or`

Comment: not able to reproduce.

Comment: `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2) is a weird error for `os.mkdir` in Windows (i.e. WinAPI `CreateDirectoryW`). If the base path doesn't exist, the error should be `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3). But even that shouldn't apply here because the base path is the current working directory from `os.getcwd()`, which Windows guarantees exists as long as it's open as the working directory.